# Azure DevOps 'az batch node list' with PowerShell ConvertFrom-Json not working

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-batch

I am working in Azure DevOps, creating an automated build process.

Doing the PowerShell command:

```
$batchNodes = az batch node list --pool-id $poolId
```

...results in a json structure complete with all Nodes in my Pool, and all Node details.  I am only looking for a list of node ids though, because I need to restart each Node in the Pool, which requires a Node id.

I expected this PowerShell command to work, but it doesn't.  ($batchNodes is blank)

```
$batchNodes = az batch node list --pool-id $poolId | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Is there a fancier or simpler method I can use to get an array of Node id values from the 'az batch node list' command results?

I'm using PowerShell 7.2.  If you know of some way to restart all of the Nodes in a Pool, please share this information.

Much thanks.

Comment: What if you wrap the command in parenthesis? i.e. `(az batch node list --pool-id $poolId) | ConvertFrom-Json`?

Comment: if `az batch node list --pool-id $poolId` outputs actual JSON text (that isn't an empty array or object) and `ConverFrom-Json` doesn't report any errors (make sure that `$ErrorActionPrreference` is at its default, `'Continue'`), `$batchNodes` cannot plausibly be blank.

Comment: You are correct mklement0.  I was trying to output the entirety of $batchNodes with a Write-Output, and it was blank.  But when I changed it to $batchNodes[0], I was able to see the data within it.

Comment: So it sounds like the problem was simply _visualizing_  the results, which can indeed be tricky with object graphs parsed from JSON with `ConvertFrom-Json`. The linked duplicate discusses solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For using Azure Cli, you could use Azure Cli task in Azure DevOps services to run the Azure Cli.

This is my sample:

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'internalsub-wsupport'
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     $batchNodes = az batch node list --pool-id mypoolwutong --account-name vwutong196420 --account-endpoint vwutong196420.eastasia.batch.azure.com | ConvertFrom-Json
```

This is the output:
[image]

Hope that could do some help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my code was working.  I was trying to output the result incorrectly.  This works:

```
$batchNodes = (az batch node list --pool-id $poolId) | ConvertFrom-Json

Write-Output "batchNodes:"
Write-Output "Index 0: $($batchNodes[0])"
```